# What is happening actually if "variable is declared but its value is never read"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, warnings

I got the same warning a lot of times when I use this pattern below.

```
function test() {
  let value: number = 0 // I get the warning here: value is declared but its value is never read

  value = 2
  
  return false 
}
```

My question is that what is really happening in this case?

Comment: Nothing is happening. And that's the point - it's useless to have an unused variable. It's very likely a mistake. If you have a variable, you *probably meant to use it*.

Comment: You set `value` to `0`, and then immediately set it to `2`. The setting to `0` is very superfluous, which is what is being pointed out to you. In this particular code you're not even using the `value` variable for anything afterwards, so it may be completely superfluous.

Comment: @deceze Warning has nothing to do with being set to 0 and then to 2. It's just that neither of those values are ever used.

Comment: @Roberto Assuming you *did* use `value` afterwards, the warning would still hold for the useless first assignment. I'll assume the `value` *is* used somewhere afterwards, since this is obviously not complete code.

Comment: @deceze But it wouldn't, the warning has nothing to do with that. Try it.

Comment: @Roberto We don't even know what tool exactly is producing this warning. My IDE for instance *will* warn about the useless first assignment. I don't know if or what React stack would warn about this, but it surely would make sense there too.

Comment: @deceze It's tslint

Answer (score -4):

That means you are not using that variable it is declared there and value is assigned to it but it is of no use. Better not to declare that variable.